# error in attaching.mdf file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

When I try to attach a .mdf file in Management Studio to open it gives me the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
  (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Unable to open the physical file "C:\DBClass\Sales.mdf".
  Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)
```

What is the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: Not sure why downvoted - I had this legitimate issue attaching a DB and found this question and solved my issue (elevated perms, and good to go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't attached in another instance of SQL Server?

**EDIT:**

Possible issues are:

- File is being held open by another process (like another instance of SQL Server)
- File is corrupt
- File is compressed (I encountered this a lot in XP)
- Actual permissions issue with the folder/file

Are you sure the MDF file is good?  Has it worked on another machine/instance in the past?

Comment: @arash - Is this for a class?  Can you confirm it works for someone else?  You didn't rename the file or anything, right?

Comment: i should test it in another system,when i tested i say the result,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Having just had the same error message, the solution for me was to run SQL Server Management Studio as Administrator (right click > Run as Administrator) and then attach the .mdf file as normal. You can then either continue with Administrator privileges or shut down Management Studio and launch again as a regular user.

Comment: Exactly the error for me. I was making a copy of a DB and reattaching it with a different name, and could do the entire process except reattach. Re-ran SSMS with elevated perms and it attached without issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the mdf file isn't read-only and that your user account has sufficient privileges to access the file?

Answer (score 0):

1st you remove log file from folder there .mdf file place
then set folder path
i set mine path
CREATE DATABASE TestDb ON
(FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDb.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO